# Python Unpack with variable values (Python 2.4.3 is version)

Tags: python, unpack

The following code works well for an unpack with a their being 2 values.

```
recvStruct = '>hhhBBhhB'
recvStructSize = (len(data) - struct.calcsize(recvStruct)) / 2
recvStruct = recvStruct + str(recvStructSize) + 'h'
recvStructSize = struct.calcsize(recvStruct)     
recvFormat = '%s%dx' % (recvStruct, len(data) - recvStructSize)
TransID , ProtoColID, PacketLength, UnitID, FC, WriteAddress, WordCount, ByteCount, datavalues[0], datavalues[1] = struct.unpack(recvFormat, data)
```

But I wish to do n values into datavalues. Is their a way other than a loop? to do in a single statement?
    TransID , ProtoColID, PacketLength, UnitID, FC, WriteAddress, WordCount, ByteCount, datavalues = struct.unpack(recvFormat, data)

This is an embedded Python 2.4

Answer (score 0):

Tuple unpacking can actually be nested:

```
unpacked = struct.unpack(recvFormat, data)
(TransID, ProtoColID, PacketLength, UnitID, FC, WriteAddress, WordCount, ByteCount), datavalues = unpacked[:8], unpacked[8:]
```

Comment: Very nice answer, thanks. Is these a way I can keep datavalues from being resized, lets say I have 5 new values I want to place and keep the last 5 (size was 10). Is there anyway? Sorry, I am new to python, you answer teach me

Comment: @JeffB I don't understand, can you clarify?

Comment: datavalues is redefined by this statement and I really just want to replace the beginning values

Comment: Ah, then replace `datavalues` with `datavalues[5:]`, where the 5 refers to the old values you're keeping, or `datavalues[-5:]` where the 5 refers to the new values you want to take in.